# Plan curvature in QGIS

Tags: qgis, saga, terrain, curvature, grass-gis

I am trying to obtain plan curvature from a DEM. So far I have tried two methods from SAGA and GrassGIS plugins, however both do not seem to work and give errors.

Do you have a workaround suggestion?

While using GrassGIS plugin, the following configuration was used to obtain slope and plan curvature:
[image: r.slope.aspect]
This resulted in two empty output files.

Following configuration was used for the SAGA plugin (file extension used .sdat and not .vrt as shown in screenshot):
[image: SAGA]

This led to the following error:
[image: saga log error]

Link to the DEM file: https://land.copernicus.eu/imagery-in-situ/eu-dem/eu-dem-v1.1?tab=download

Comment: You need to provide more information (like what and how you try with SAGA and GRASS and what didn't work...)

Comment: @J.R Thanks for the suggestion; I have added some screenshots to the original post.